# Serializing custom function in spacy for multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, spacy, python-decorators

I have a custom entity scrubber function that basically tells textrank algorithm(using this to extract key phrases) to avoid tagging certain entities as key phrases.
I register this function to spacy using:

```
@spacy.registry.misc("entity_scrubber")
def articles_scrubber():
    def scrubber_func(span: Span) -> str:
        for token in span:
            if token.ent_type_ in ['CARDINAL', 'DATE', 'MONEY', 'ORDINAL', 'PERCENT',
                                 'PERSON', 'QUANTITY', 'TIME']: # people, places, dates 
                # ignore named entities
                return "INELIGIBLE_PHRASE"
        return span.text
    return scrubber_func
```

I add the textrank component using the following line of code and also pass the custom function in the config parameter:

```
nlp.add_pipe("textrank", config={"scrubber": {"@misc": "entity_scrubber"}})
```

I try to process the docs using the nlp.pipe method and spacy's multiprocessing capability by passing n_process param

```
nlp.pipe(docs, n_process=8, disable=['tok2vec','tagger','lemmatizer', 'attribute_ruler'])
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'articles_scrubber.<locals>.scrubber_func'
```

After exploring online,  I found that decorating the function in this way(nested functions) won't be pickable. I have found some solutions online which(http://gael-varoquaux.info/programming/decoration-in-python-done-right-decorating-and-pickling.html, https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-wrap-decorators-in-python-5ac3676835f9) show how to decorate the functions right away so that they are pickable, but I couldn't find any approach in reference to spacy.

Can someone point me in a direction on how can I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the function being decorated but rather that the actual *worker* function that will be invoked in the new process is not at global scope. In the following demo I have a decorator `time_it` that prints out the running time of the function being decorated. I use it to decorate both the function `get_worker_function` that returns the worker function that will run in a child process as well as to decorate that worker function, `foo`, itself. There is no problem when the worker function is at global scope:

```py
from timing import time_it
from multiprocessing import Process

@time_it
def foo():
    print("It works!")

@time_it
def get_worker_function():
    # Return actual worker function
    return foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker_function = get_worker_function()
    p = Process(target=worker_function)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Prints:

```None
func: get_worker_function args: [(), {}] took: 6e-07 sec.
It works!
func: foo args: [(), {}] took: 0.0001581 sec.
```

But if the worker function is not at global scope, then you get an error:

```py
from timing import time_it
from multiprocessing import Process


@time_it
def get_worker_function():
    # Return actual worker function
    def foo():
        print("It works!")
    return foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker_function = get_worker_function()
    p = Process(target=worker_function)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Prints:

```None
func: get_worker_function args: [(), {}] took: 7e-07 sec.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'get_worker_function.<locals>.foo'
```

**Solution?**

Try changing your code to this:

```py
def scrubber_func(span: Span) -> str:
    for token in span:
        if token.ent_type_ in ['CARDINAL', 'DATE', 'MONEY', 'ORDINAL', 'PERCENT',
                             'PERSON', 'QUANTITY', 'TIME']: # people, places, dates 
            # ignore named entities
            return "INELIGIBLE_PHRASE"
    return span.text

@spacy.registry.misc("entity_scrubber")
def articles_scrubber():
    return scrubber_func
```